# Show that $1-\frac{2}{5}+\frac{3}{9}-\frac{4}{13}+\cdots$ is Cesaro summable to $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x^4)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's my way to do this, consider $a_n= \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\frac{k}{4k-3}$, and then 
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}(a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n)&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^{j-1}\frac{j}{4j-3}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n (-1)^{j-1}\frac{j}{4j-3}\sum_{k=j}^n1\\              &=\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}\frac{j}{4j-3}\left(1-\frac{j-1}{n}\right)
\end{align}
$$

I try to write the last one as the partial sum of the form of Riemann integral, but I can't find a good way to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Cesàro-summability preserves additivity and extends the usual notion of convergence. Since
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{1}{4}\stackrel{\text{Cesàro}}{=}\frac{1}{8} \tag{1}$$
we have:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{k}{4k-3}\stackrel{\text{Cesàro}}{=}\frac{1}{8}+\frac{3}{4}\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{4k-3} \tag{2}$$
where the last series is conditionally convergent (in the usual sense) to:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^{k-1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{4k-2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^{k-1}x^{4k-2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^2}{1+x^4}\,dx\tag{3} $$
and the claim boils down to showing that
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(1+x^4)^2}=\frac{1}{32} \left(4+3 \sqrt{2} \left(\pi -\log\left(3-2 \sqrt{2}\right)\right)\right) \tag{4}$$
not that difficult through partial fraction decomposition. In a single step,
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^{k-1}\frac{k}{4k-3}&\stackrel{\text{Cesàro}}{=}&\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\frac{(n+1)}{(4n+1)}\\&\stackrel{\text{Cesàro}}{=}&\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n (n+1) x^{4n}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(1+x^4)^2}.\tag{5}\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: I have a lot of questions about this. How does (2) follows from (1). Where is (3) used? Where do you show (4)? Where does the last equality in (5) come from? Why is it only Cesaro equality for the first two equalities in (5)?